# React testing library => How to get access to Portal element, when portal show up after clicking a button

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to test this scenario:

I get the input filed, and when I click on the input, the dropdown with options is open, but this dropdown is in the Portal.

How can I grab this element from DOM and check if all options are displayed well, or just test if I can click on each option?

Right now when I test this component, which includes input with dropdown looks like this

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <HeaderInfo config={config} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

and I have access in react test library to all dom elements in , but the problem is that, when I click on the input, dropdown compontent is rendered outside of this component, juz next to the root element as it is in React.

My question is how can I get this Portal element using react-library?